# OpenCV throwing error. Trying to use a Random Forest Model

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, regression, random-forest

So I'm trying to use opencv to create a regression model.

I'm using this but I can't figure out what's wrong: http://pastebin.com/9vEpn4GC

It's always throwing this out:

> OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (type mask must be 8uC1 or 8sC1 array) in cvPreprocessVarType, file ........\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp, line 519
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> a.train(save_all[features[i]], cv2.CV_ROW_SAMPLE, Y[:][:, i], params=params, varType=var_types)
>   cv2.error: ........\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp:519: error: (-210) type mask must be 8uC1 or 8sC1 array in function cvPreprocessVarType

I've tried searching this error but there aren't many results. I guess it involves the var_types declaration.

Comment: How about `var_types = np.array([cv2.CV_VAR_NUMERICAL] * var_n + [cv2.CV_VAR_ORDERED], np.uint8)`? It's a list of enumeration values, having that as floats doesn't make sense.

Comment: And the error message is specifically saying "type mask must be 8uC1 or 8sC1 array", which I take it means it wants either unsigned or signed 8-bit values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var_types` array is a list of enumeration values. As the error message hints, the data type of the elements should be a byte, not float.

The following should do the trick:

```
var_types = np.array([cv2.CV_VAR_NUMERICAL] * var_n + [cv2.CV_VAR_ORDERED], np.uint8)
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, first time using opencv. 
Now I get: 

OpenCV Error: Bad argument (type mask must be of <input var count> + 1 size) in cvPreprocessVarType

Comment: @AndréCosta What's the shape of `save_all[features[i]]` before you call train? What's the shape of `var_types` ? I don't have the data files to try it with...

Comment: That was the problem my var_n was wrong because I was using my first input shape without it being processed to smaller matrices. I've manually assigned var_n and now everything is working :)

Many thanks for your help!